# How to evaluate $i^{i^i}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I find complex exponentials a bit confusing. I appreciate if you let me know whether this attempt is correct:

$$i^{i^i}=e^{i^i\ln(i)}=e^{(\frac{-\pi}{2}+2k\pi)(i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi))}\quad\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Edit: I meant
$$i^{i^i}=e^{i^i\ln(i)}=e^{e^{(\frac{-\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}(i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi))}\quad\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Have you considered what the definition of $z^w$ is for $z,w\in\Bbb{C}$?

Comment: You need parenthesis to make this unambiguous. Unless you want to solve for both interpretations.

Comment: I forgot an e in my answer. I meant $i^{i^i}=e^{i^iln(i)}=e^{e^{(\frac{-\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}(i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi))}\ \ \ \ \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The primitive value of $i^i$ is $e^{-\pi/2}$

Comment: Why not use different values of $k$ for the two logs?

Comment: So $i^{i^i}=e^{i^iln(i)}=e^{e^{(\frac{-\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}(i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi))}\ \ \ \ \ \ n,k\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Are you trying to find $(i^i)^i$ or $i^{(i^i)}$?  These are not the same thing

Comment: It should be $i^{{(i}^i)}$

Comment: See equations (16) through (18) in this [power tower](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) article. That is your principal branch answer.

Comment: From your comment don't you mean then $$i^{(i^i)}=i^{(e^{i \log\,i})}=e^{\log\,(i){e^{i \log\,(i)}}}$$